# Multidimensional array with strtok

Tags: c

Is it possible to use `strtok` on a two-dimensional array? Or, can it only be used on one dimension (due to its global nature), such as the outer. For example:

```
char * token = strtok(arr, "\n"), * token_i;
do {
    printf ("|%s|\n", token);
    strcpy(inner, token);

    // inner
    token_i = strtok(inner, ",");      // <-- will this corrupt the outer too?
    while (token_i != NULL) { */
        printf("-%s-", token_i);
        token_i = strtok(NULL, ",");
     }


} while (token = strtok(NULL, "\n"));
```

Comment: What is `inner`? where is it declared?

Comment: If you are concerned about the nature of `strtok` having an internal state, you can use `strtok_r`

Comment: @GovindParmar `inner` and `arr` are both character arrays, something like `char inner[50]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtok()` only has one "slot" for an in-progress tokenization.

Even if it did have more than one slot, the follow-up calls take just a `NULL` -- there's no way to tell that one particular `strtok(NULL, x)` call should refer to a different tokenization than another `strtok(NULL, x)` call.

(That is, without other factors from the surrounding environment, like having the unrelated `strtok()` calls come from different threads, which could work if the implementation stored the hidden data in thread-local storage.)

On POSIX systems, you can use [`strtok_r()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) instead:

> Different strings may be parsed concurrently using sequences of
> calls to strtok_r() that specify different saveptr arguments.

Answer (score 3):

No, this will not work.  As soon as you do the `strtok( inner, "," );` you lose the search context in `arr` because `strtok` maintains its state in a single instance, and that instance gets overwritten with every call.

If either `strtok_r` or `strtok_s` are available to you, use those.  Otherwise, you'll have to fully tokenize `arr`, saving all the different tokens somewhere, then tokenize each of those tokens.